# getting the value through key in the dictionary

Tags: objective-c

I need to get the value for the particular key in the map,

```
id val = [m_cAppIdMap valueForKey:wTimerIds];
```

where `wTimerIds` is a unsigned short integer.

> Runtime exception:EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>
> Warning: passing argument 1 of
>   'valueForKey:' makes pointer from
>   integer without a cast

EDITED:

```
 NSNumber* val = [m_cAppIdMap valueForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];
```

The warning i'm getting is,
incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSNumber *', expected 'struct NSString *' when 
passing argument 1 of 'valueForKey:' from distinct Objective-C type

The runtime exception i'm getting is,
[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100110c20

I am storing the the key as a unsignedshort in the dictioanry.so i'm trying to search for the value in the dictionary with that data type.

Comment: Try this id* val = [m_cAppIdMap valueForKey:wTimerIds];

Comment: Or This id* val = (id*)[m_cAppIdMap valueForKey:wTimerIds];

Comment: @viTo Brothers:I tried whta you told me to do.But its still with errors dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
NSNumber *wTimerIdsNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:wTimerIds];
id val = [m_cAppIdMap objectForKey:wTimerIdsNum];
```

Comment: still i'm with  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100110c20
 and /NSArray/NSArray1.m:107:0 /NSArray/NSArray1.m:107: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSNumber *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'valueForKey:' from distinct Objective-C type


warnings

Comment: @ron what type is a m_cAppIdMap variable? try objectForKey: instead if valueForKey.

Comment: Thanks dude it worked.The value that is stored is a pointer to the structure which is an object.

Comment: edit your answer with objectForKey so that i could accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can not have primitive integer as key. Keys must be object. You can wrap that integer to a `NSString` to use as a key.

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wTimerIds];
[m_cAppIdMap setValue:val forKey:key];
id val = [m_cAppIdMap valueForKey:key];
```

Or you can wrap that in `NSNumber` too. You need to use the same thing for both setting and getting. That is, if you use string in `setValue:forKey:` then you need to use string for `valueForKey:`. Similarly if you use `NSNumber` then you need to use that in both place.

Comment: Why convert to a string when there's a perfectly good number object type?

Comment: It's just that many people, including me :-), prefer only strings as keys. Though number is perfectly fine. I have edited my answer.

Comment: The value i'm retreiving is a pointer to the structure.Its showing me a null value.But actually the value for the key is present in the dictionary.

Comment: How you are adding values in dictionary?